# What is passed to the parameter cb in this instance?

Tags: node.js

I am learning Node JS right now and I am confused by the snippet of code below. `Dosomething` is called in the code later on without any parameters. So what is the value `cb` set to (since there were no parameters passed)?

```
let dosomething = (cb) => {
checkAuthToken.get((err, authKey) => {
    if (err) {
        return cb(err)
    }

    return cb(null, authKey);
})

}
```

Comment: That must be a mistake or a misunderstanding. Passing nothing to that function makes `cb` equal to `undefined`. And that will result in an error as you cannot call a function on `undefined`.

Comment: cb will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

**@UZA**, here in your code, **dosomething()** is a function that takes 1 parameter as another callback function.

In case if error, you are calling that callback function with 1 error parameter **err**.

In case of success, you are calling the callback with 2 parameters **null** & **authKey**.

You have used arrow functions in your code. I think, it is making you doubtful.

> Please comment if you the explanation doesn't solve your problem. I will update my answer with more examples.

Here I have shown 2 simple examples.

#### » Simple function syntax

```
function doSomething(cb) {
  if(true) {
         cb("I am a programmer"); 
  }
}

// Call doSomething() with 1 parameter as a function
doSomething(
function (message) {
   console.log(message); // I am a programmer
})
```

#### » Arrow function syntax (implementation of above code using arrow functions)

```
var doSomething = (cb) => {
  if(true) {
         cb("I am a programmer"); 
  }
}

// Call doSomething() with 1 parameter as a function
doSomething (
 (message) => {
   console.log(message); // I am a programmer
})
```